# Problems creating service using sc.exe

Tags: windows-service

I have this command to create a service:

`sc create svnserve binpath="\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service --root C:\SVNRoot" displayname="Subversion" depend=tcpip start=auto obj="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"`

Unfortunately, it seems not to work, even though the syntax is correct. When I run it, I get the usage instructions (which I guess is a way of telling me that I've supplied incorrect arguments, although I have no idea what incorrect argument I might have supplied).

Can anyone help me out of my difficulty? Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your syntax is actually incorrect, but you'll be forgiven for missing it.

From the help text for `sc create`:

```
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
```

What isn't immediately obvious from this is that the options need to be specified with a space between the option name and the value.

Incorrect:

```
displayname="Subversion"
```

Correct (note the space after `=`):

```
displayname= "Subversion"
```

Your command should work just fine formatted accordingly, i.e.:

```
sc create svnserve binpath= "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service --root C:\SVNRoot" displayname= "Subversion" depend= tcpip start= auto obj= "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"
```

Comment: Voted your response as the answer, because it was more detailed. Thanks!

Comment: This no longer appears to be an issue in windows 10. It appears to work for me, if anyone else wants to verify this.

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 15):

you need spaces after =

> displayname= "Subversion Server"
>           depend=  Tcpip
>           start=  auto

Comment: +1 - The sc syntax confuses first-time users w/ the need for spaces after arguments.

Comment: I've been using it for years and it still trips me up occasionally. :-(